# not able to add bibliographies in latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

At the initial stage, I wrote individual chapters for my master's thesis. Now, it is time to integrate the all chapters. Main.tex file is being created to include all the chapters. Unfortunately, tutorials are confusing when I try to add the bibliographies. I use apa style of bibliography.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title{
    {Reflections on Exile}
    {\large Unversity of Harvard}\\
    {\includegraphics{unibremen.png}}
}

\author{Python Buddha}
\date{02 March 2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\include{chapter1.tex}
... 
\end{document}
```

**chapter1.tex**

```
\section{What is Lorem Ipsum?}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text\parentcite{microworlds}.
```

Comment: what is biber please?

Comment: \printbibliography is there but still not resolved the problem.

Comment: `\biber` is completley new for me. yes, `\parencite` resolved my problem. There is no printed bibliography.

Comment: yes, `referenced.bib` contains this reference:

@webpage{microworlds,
 Date-Modified = {2019-08-20 17:15:58 +0200},
 Month = {July},
 Note = {[Online; accessed 12-July-2019]},
 Title = {Micro Worlds},
 Url = {http://www.microworlds.com/},
 Year = {2019},
 Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.microworlds.com/}}

Comment: do you mean to include `biber` inside package comment?

Comment: `biber` is the program that actually processes your `.bib` file. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701) for an explanation. You need to tell your editor to process the document using `biber` rather than `bibtex` (which is usually the default for most editing environments.) See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751) for how to do this.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 has some more background on what Biber does, but for most people the question Alank linked (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) is more important. (Also it is probably only a typo, but just for the record the command is called `\parencite` not `\parentcite` - there should be no **`t`**.)

Comment: Any news here? As the question stands now it is (apart from the obvious typo) pretty much a candidate for duplication with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751.